# Multiline title in dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

How can I have a JQuery Dialog with a title that is more than one line?

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/VKcJ7/7/

I've tried using a newline character, and fiddling with the JQuery UI CSS classes for the title & titlebar, but nothing seems to be working.

JS: / JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Something really long wow \n too much to have in a title but oh well'
        //adding the newline character \n does nothing!
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-title{

}

.ui-dialog-titlebar{

}
```

Comment: did you try putting in a `<br />`?

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah, it just comes out as part of the title text

Comment: @DanielA.White - That too doesnt work as  text-overflow: ellipsis is present for ui-dialog-title.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VKcJ7/9/

Comment: What was the point of adding the empty CSS to your question?

Comment: @j08691 just so people answering could know which UI CSS classes they could use to solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.ui-dialog-title` has the css to make overflowing text to be truncated to ... (ellipsis).

```
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Using the below css instead should fix this.

```
white-space: normal;
```

Edit:

making `white-space: normal` will ignore the `text-overflow` declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Just set the `white-space` attribute to `normal`

```
 .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-title{
     white-space: normal;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VKcJ7/20/

Comment: Right. white-space normal will just ignore the text-overflow declaration. no need to mess with text-overflow ellipsis declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The anwser is pretty simple. 
jQuery UI is adding a

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

to every title.

Just use this code in your CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-title{
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Be sure to load your CSS  AFTER the jquery-ui css files, to be shure to load your settings.
Otherwise you'd have to use the '!important' like this:

```
.ui-dialog-title{
   white-space: normal !important;
}
```

which is ugly